# Java application that uses multiple timers

Tags: java, timer, timertask

Hi all and thanks for reading this.
i have an application and i want to use multiple timers on it. 
it will read from a list of instructions some instructions and will tell you what to do, keeping track of time for each instruction's time and notifying you when timer is over. instruction can include other instructions and goes on.
i m passing the time as : **double minutes** to each instruction.

**So it should work like this.**

start instruction1 - start timer1

if it includes other, start instruction1.1 - start timer1.1

start instruction2 - start timer2 .....etc.etc..

every time a timer goes of it should notify me

**i would like to get suggestions on how to do this....**
any tutorials, examples, links pseudocode, sample code are welcome. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[Introducing a simple generalisation of the Java language's Timer class](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-schedule/index.html)

[How to Use Timers](http://www.iam.ubc.ca/guides/javatut99/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

[Job Scheduling using Timer and Quartz](http://oreilly.com/pub/a/java/archive/quartz.html?page=1)

Comment: i read all the links and i need to decide. Timer or Quartz... i might be able to do what i need with timer but i m not sure if quartz will make it easier. Do you know if Quartz is widely used and if i can get support if i m stuck? Anyone used quartz?

Comment: This will help to decide what to use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750226/what-is-a-good-open-source-job-scheduler-in-java